# Creating master process and connecting slave processes

Tags: linux, shell-script, linux-mint, scripting, terminal

Google-fu failed me on this issue as I have no idea what are the correct keywords and this is my first time encountering such an issue.

I am using Linux Mint and I am trying to run a program called Espresso to perform a simulation with it called "replica exchange". Essentially, what I do right now is to create a master process in one terminal via the command:

```
Espresso peptidebuilder.tcl peptide.tcl -replica
```

Then, I create slave processes to connect to this master process by opening a new window and issuing the command:

```
Espresso peptidebuilder.tcl peptide.tcl -replica -connect
```

If I need 12 slave processes, I open 12 terminal windows and issue the same command in each terminal. Is there any method for me to create a script to handle the entire flow, from creating the master process to connecting as many slave processes as I need?

Comment: Sure, you could fire off `xterm` or `screen` or `tmux` to create the terminals needed, or fake them with `expect`, etc.